# Detect the element in an array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like

```
var array1 = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'test2'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'test3'
    }
]

var array2=[
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'test2'
    }
]
```

I want to loop through array 1 and find the same object and add more property in array 1

I have something like

```
 for(var i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
     if(array2[i].id == array1[i].id){
         alert('find!')
     } 
 }
```

I understand my above codes don't work because the index is different. Can someone help me about this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a nested loop with a different variable for the index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: You're going to have to deep compare the objects, as well as looping the array.

Comment: ...I assume your definition of "same object" is two objects with matching `.id` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the IDs in `array2` are all unique, I would create an object whose keys are the IDs:

```
var obj2 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    obj2[array2[i].id] = array2[i];
}
```

Then I would use this to find matching elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (obj2[array1[i].id]) {
        alert("find!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s time for **ECMA5**

```
var array1 = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'test',
      foo: {
        bar: 'bar',
        quux: 'quux'
      }
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'test2'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'test3'
    }
];

function equal(objA, objB) {
    if(Object.keys(objA).length !== Object.keys(objB).length) {
        return false;
    }

    var areEqual = Object.keys(objA).every(function(key) {
        if(typeof objA[key] === "object") {
            return equal(objA[key], objB[key]);
        }
        return objA[key] === objB[key];
    });

    return  areEqual;
}

function hasElement(array, element) {
    return array.some(function(el) {
        return equal(el, element);
    });
}

console.log(hasElement(array1, {
  id: '1',
  name: 'test',
  foo: {
    bar: 'bar',
        quux: 'quux'
    }
}));
```